# how to set page orientation(landscape or portrait) in phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I want to set pagesetup in excel using phpspreadsheet. I found to do it using phpexcel from [here](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/04/18/setting-your-worksheet-printing-layout-options-in-phpexcel/). I do not know what to replace at PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.

```
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I tried it after go through PageSetup.php in PHPSpreadsheet.

```
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 3):

Acording to the documentation, this is te correct way to set:

```php
// for orientation
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

// paper size
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
```

Comment: $sheet=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()