# Laravel Excel landscape page

Tags: php, excel, laravel, landscape, laravel-excel

I'm using [Laravel-Excel](https://laravel-excel.com) to create excel files with Laravel. I need to set page orientation to `landscape`, But I can't find the solution in official documentation. By the way I'm using Blade to create excel file and this is my code.

```
class ExampleExcel implements FromView, WithEvents {

    public function view(): View {
        return view('excel.main');
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            },
        ];
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It uses phpSpreadsheet so you should get the spreadsheet object then set the landscape. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939915/how-to-set-page-orientationlandscape-or-portrait-in-phpspreadsheet

Comment: @AnuratChapanond - I think this solution is not working for version 3.1. There's no `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding `BeforeSheet` event like this.

```php
return [
    BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {
        $event->sheet
            ->getPageSetup()
            ->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use beforeSheet event to get spreadsheet object then in the event you can set orientation.

```
public static function beforeSheet(BeforeSheet $event)
{
    $event->sheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()
        ->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

You can read more about events at https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/extending.html